# How to know when a file or folder is accessed (in real time)

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I need to show some data when users access folders and files in SharePoint 2010. Each item has its own data, so I need to raise an event when they access a certain file/folder and then show the propoer data in a webpart.

Is it possible to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable Item level Auditing and then read the Audit log:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397403(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: That won't work for me, because I need to show info at the time a file is accessed, not after that. If I used auditing for this, I would have to have a process that runs every second, and that's not performant.

Comment: Well, I was hoping SharePoint give me tools for raising events when users did something, as accessing files, folders, etc.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to create event handler to raised the event on itemupdating.

hope this help.